# Captured Variable IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have two code looped snippets latter works as expected while the former throws exception. Why does  `foreach` work while `for` loop doesn't? What does it stem from?

```
IEnumerable<char> query = "Not what you might expect";

query = query.Where (c => c != 'a');
query = query.Where (c => c != 'e');
query = query.Where (c => c != 'i');
query = query.Where (c => c != 'o');
query = query.Where (c => c != 'u');

foreach (char c in query) Console.Write (c);  // Nt wht y mght xpct
```

For loop with exception

```
IEnumerable<char> query = "Not what you might expect";
string vowels = "aeiou";

for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
  query = query.Where (c => c != vowels[i]);

foreach (char c in query) Console.Write (c);
```

`foreach` code,

```
foreach (char vowel in vowels)
  query = query.Where (c => c != vowel);

foreach (char c in query) Console.Write (c);
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 2):

Well, *Linq* uses *lazy* (deffered execution), so you have:

```
// Just a declaration, query doesn't execute
for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
  query = query.Where (c => c != vowels[i]);

// now, after the for loop, i is equal to vowels.Length

// Here, query executes with current i value, i == vowels.Length
// And you have an out of range exception
foreach (char c in query) Console.Write (c);
```

Comment: This answer doesn’t really explain why the two seemingly equivalent methods produce different results. The fact that execution is deferred is true for both examples. The real reason for the difference is that C# 5 took a breaking change to make the foreach loop not close over the loop variable, but left the for loop behavior the same.

Comment: @DaveM as well as he is really experienced guy, his answer is right but if possible a bit more explanation would be better. It is exactly due to _lazy eval_ +1

Comment: It has nothing to do with lazy eval. It has everything to do with how closures and variable capturing work in C#.

Comment: @DaveM: it must have _something_ "to do with lazy eval", since if the `Where()` method invoked the delegate immediately when it's called, instead of lazily after the loop has completed, the issue would not exist. I don't see how you can say it literally has _nothing_ to do with lazy evaluation.